# How can I configure Nginx to block specific bots to access the site but allow them to access robots.txt?

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx configuration to block certain bots to access the site based on the user agent. It works great so far however I found that the blocked bots couldn't access `/robots.txt` file as well, so they continue to crawl the site with hundreds of 403 errors every day.

```
map $http_user_agent $block_ua {
    default            0;
    ~*yandexbot        1;
}

server {
    # Block bad bots
    if ($block_ua) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # other location blocks below...
}
```

I tried to change the configuration to allow all bots to access `/robots.txt`, as follows, but it doesn't work, testing with `curl -I -A "yandexbot" [url]` still return **403 Forbidden**.

```
server {
    location = /robots.txt {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Block bad bots
    if ($block_ua) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # other location blocks below...
}
```

What should I add in the configuration to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

First off, try to add [`allow all;`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) to your Nginx config. The rest in the example below is optional:

```
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

Then you can try something along the lines of that:

```
if ($block_ua) { 
    set $test A; 
} 
if ($request_uri = /robots.txt) { 
    set $test B; 
} 
if ($test = A) { 
    return 403; 
}
```

This is a hacky way to have multiple `if` statements. See [here](https://gist.github.com/jrom/1760790).

**Explanation**:

> `allow all`

Allows access for the specified network or address (In this case all).

---

> `log_not_found off;`

If the file does not exist and a client requests it, do not log an HTTP Error 404.

---

> `if ($request_uri = /robots.txt) { set $test A; }`

If the requested file is not `robots.txt`, set `$test` to "A"

---

> `if ($block_ua){ set $test "${test}B"; }`

If the UserAgent matches, set `$test` to "$test + B"

---

> `if ($test = AB){ return 403; }`

If `$test` is "AB", meaning both conditions are met, return `403` and block the bot.

---

**Additional information:**

Blocking the UserAgent header only blocks *some* bots. Everything the client sends can be spoofed. Including the UserAgent string.

Comment: The solution doesn't work, and breaks the site, the "location ~ ^/(?!(robots\.txt))" block has suppressed all location blocks below it in particular the block that process php, so php file is downloaded as file in the website!

Comment: @KokHui See my edits. Please let me know if it worked

Comment: The 2nd solution doesn't work, "if (!-e robots.txt)" seems to always evaluate to true, regardless what I put in the filename, eg. "if (!-e xxx.txt)" evaluates to true.

Comment: I found the solution, using $request_uri:

        if ($block_ua) {
                set $test A;
        }
        if ($request_uri = /robots.txt) {
                set $test B;
        }
        if ($test = A) {
                return 403;
        }

Comment: Could you try to write `if (!-e robots\.txt){` ? I'm curious if that line gets handled as regex. Otherwise I will edit the answer

Comment: @KokHui Hmm... Thats odd. Well, edited the answer for other people with the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!